moodle error/ You have tried to install latest version of Edwiser Bridge plugin
I'm trying to connect moodle with edwiser bridge to an updated moodle site which had edwiser installed.
When I try to install a new version of edwiser plugin for moodle I run through this error.

error/ You have tried to install latest version of Edwiser Bridge plugin, but we have noticed you are still using older version of edwiser bridge plugins. please remove older version of moodle edwiser bridge, moodle single sign on and moodle bulk purchase plugin and then try to install the Edwiser Bridge plugin again.

although I can't see the edwiser plugin installed when I go to site administration > plugins > plugin overview. Nor I can see it on the moodle folders(/html/local/).
The only edwiser plugin I have installed is wdmgroupregistration, but when I uninstall it I get this error (error/An error occurred whilst communicating with the server). and I lose access to my moodle website.
Here's a video explaining the error.
when I install edwiser
when I delete wdmgroupregistration
thanks in advance for your help and time.
I tried to purge cache,
I tried to install wdmgroupregistration and delete it.
have edwiser bridge installed successfully.

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Is there a reason that you restored the spelling mistakes?

The error message string is in /auth/edwiserbridge/lang/en/auth_edwiserbridge.php
$string['edwiserbridgepropluginrequired'] = " You have tried to install latest version of Edwiser Bridge plugin, but we have noticed you are still using older version of edwiser bridge plugins. please remove older version of moodle edwiser bridge, moodle single sign on and moodle bulk purchase plugin and then try to install the Edwiser Bridge plugin again.";

So I searched for edwiserbridgepropluginrequired in the code, the message is displayed if auth_edwiserbridge_check_pro_dependancy() returns false
The function returns false if one of these plugins is installed

local/edwiserbridge
local/wdmgroupregistration
auth/wdmwpmoodle

And it look like the wdmgroupregistration plugin isn't open source, so you'll need to contact edwiser for support
https://edwiser.org/documentation/bulk-purchase/plugin-installation/
